# Skip rows in an unsorted list

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

I have an Angular app which displays a list and a Scala API which provides data. I encountered a problem (and the languages don't matter, is just about logic).

The problem is that the table from which I get data doesn't have a primary key. Because I need to display the data plain in a widget (of type table) without sorts, just like in the database, I just do "`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 30`".

The problem is when I want to change the page, my query became `SELECT * FROM table OFFSET 30 LIMIT 30`

> ERROR: OFFSET can not be used without an ORDER BY option.

How can be solved this problem?

Comment: There is no default order in a mysql table, if you dont have an ODER BY you can get data in any order, and no necessarily the same unordered order from 2 queries

Comment: You're going to need to decide on which column to order. If it doesn't matter, pick one with a simple representation (like integer) so sorting is fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you have to have an `order by` clause in order to use the `offset` clause. If you don't have any meaningful way of sorting the table, you could just pick some arbitrary value, like the first column:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable ORDER BY column1 OFFSET 30 LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Thanks. I expected more answers, but how this is the only, I accept it as the solution. Anyway, I can't imaginate another idea to solve this.